# Роли пользователей laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

как в ларавель создавать группы пользователей? создать модель Roles и установить связь с users hasOne и belongsTo?

Comment: Взгляните на пакет https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: не совсем разобрался, после установки, как мне записать уже готовый список ролей - преподаватель, ученик. администратор, пользователь, через базу phpadmin?

Comment: $user->assignRole('писатель'); вот таким способом я например могу сменить роль в личном кабинете

Comment: а например как сделать вывод всех ролей и выбрав нужную потом установить?

Comment: Посмотрите внимательнее документацию, там все очень хорошо написано. Вы публикуете миграции таблиц `roles` и `permissions` после этого хоть через тинкер Вы можете создавать роль через `Role::create();`. Вывод всех ролей идет через `Role::all()`